# Branch deepLink url redirects to the app, but BranchSDK always returning `clicked_branch_link: false`

Tags: android, react-native, branch.io

I've configured branch.io in my react native app and it was working perfectly in `iOS`. But, in `Android` I'm facing issue. I've two activities `MainActivity` and `SplashActivity` in the `Android` app. I've setup scheme and intent filters for `SplashActivity`, also I've overridden `onStart` and `onNewIntent` methods as given in the branch.io `Android` setup docs. On clicking the deeplink URL android app is opening, but I'm not getting the link params. When I observe the logs in android, `BranchSDK` always returns:
`"data":"{\"+clicked_branch_link\":false,\"+is_first_session\":false}"`
 though the app is opened through deeplink url.

I've tried all the possible ways of googling this issue. But, couldn't find any solution. In `iOS`I'm getting the link params as expected but not in `Android`. I've tried moving those intent filters to `MainActivity` but that doesn't bring any luck. I'm a `JavaScript` developer and have no knowledge on `Android` code. I've just followed the docs to setup in `Android`.

Please help me in resolving this `Android` issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is Devesh from Branch's Integration team.

We have created a ticket(#80498) for you and have replied back to sunanda93.padala@gmail.com asking for the required information to investigate this further.

Looking forward to your response on the ticket.

Thanks,
Devesh